# Replace string and next one using sed

Tags: sed

I know how to replace sting via sed:

```
sed -i "s|.*#app-${BRANCH}-log.*|    Path ${LOG_PATH}    #app-${BRANCH}-log|" /etc/td-agent-bit/td-agent-bit.conf
```

and this is work for file like

```
[INPUT]
Name tail
Path /var/lib/docker/containers/f774c1a3689dfffb2528833ac2ded629c3b1873fd3af96fe0cf1f041f22f88d8/f774c1a3689dfffb2528833ac2ded629c3b1873fd3af96fe0cf1f041f22f88d8-json.log  #app-develop-log
Tag app.develop
Interval_Sec 1
```

but how to replace next line? for example:

```
#This line just for triggering sed
And this one must be replaced
```

Any idea? Sorry for my horrible English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/^#This line just for triggering sed$/{n;s/.*/foo/}' file
```

Output:

```
#This line just for triggering sed
foo
```

---

See: `man sed`